How to wait for a background subprocess to complete before proceeding to more operations?
I have a program that performs a calculation, ran from the command line on a Linux terminal.  It uses a command like
program_name -i input_file -o output_file1 -r output_file2 -w dependency1 -d dependency2

I have a wrapper script in Python that I am using to do some file handling and executing the above command.  The script is being ran executed from the Linux terminal as well.  Since the calculation program can take a long time to run (from minutes to hours), I would like to be able to nohup the terminal output (CPU and program time written to output every 10sec) to a file and send the process to the background so that I can continue with other terminal operations.  The command I'm actually trying to execute as a subprocess is
program_name -i input_file -o output_file1 -r output_file2 -w dependency1 -d dependency2 </dev/null >output.log 2>&1 &

The problem is program_name and its dependencies are stored in a shared network location, due to limitations on argument length I can't run the program using paths to the program/files.  I need to create symbolic links to the program/files, run the program, and then unlink the program and files.  If I run the subprocess in the terminal foreground, this works fine.  However, when I try to run the subprocess in the background, Python won't wait for it to complete before moving onto the next piece of code, which is unlinking the program and dependencies and subsequently causing the program to fail.
My code works like this
# create symbolic links
for file in [program_name, dependency1, dependency2, dependency3]:
    src = path_to_program / file
    dst = current_directory / file

    try:
        os.symlink(src, dst)
    except FileExistsError:
        pass

# create command
cmd = "program_name -i {inp} -o {out1} -r {out2} -w {dep1} -d {dep2} </dev/null >output.log 2>&1 &".format(
    inp=input_file
    out1=output_file1
    out2=output_file2
    dep1=dependency1
    dep2=dependency2
)         

proc = subprocess.run(cmd, stderr=None, stdout=None, shell=True)

# remove symbolic links
for file in [program_name, dependency1, dependency2, dependency3]:
    os.unlink(current_directory / file)

If the subprocess is ran in foreground by removing the end & the script waits for the subprocess to complete before unlinking the files.  If ran in background, as soon as the subprocess is started the script proceeds to unlink the files and break the subprocess.
What am I missing?  As far as I understand subprocess.run() should wait for the subprocess to complete before continuing, but it doesn't appear to be doing so.  I've also tried using subprocess.Popen() with .wait() and .communicate() ,subprocess.call() ,subprocess.check_call() , and os.system()  and got the same behavior with all of them.
If I try to use shell=False like
proc = subprocess.run(shlex.split(cmd), stderr=None, stdout=None, shell=False)

Then program_name tries reading in </dev/null >output.log 2>&1 & as arguments and returns errors.

Why does the subprocess need to run in the background?
Can you run the wrapping python script in the background (but have that script invoke subprocesses in its foreground)

How would you be able to “continue with other terminal operations” if the Python process were still running (waiting to unlink things) and it wasn’t backgrounded?

If you are using the shell to start a background process, the shell exits immediately, and Python has no idea when program_name actually completes.
Don't use the shell. Execute program_name directly, and use the facilities of subprocess to do I/O redirection instead of shell constructs.
cmd = ["program_name", 
       "-i",  input_file,
       "-o",  output_file1,
       "-r", output_file2,
       "-w", dependency1,
       "-d", dependency2]

with open("output.log", "w") as f:
    proc = subprocess.run(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=f)

Now Python is monitoring program_name itself, and subprocess.run will return when program_name completes.
(This is also more robust against things like file names containing spaces, and other issues that can arise when building a string for the shell to parse.)
